# About extending core classes in PHP ( Example Soap Client )

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I have being developing in PHP since a while now and I never had the situation where I need to extend from a core class in PHP.

I have an issue that I have a Soap Webservices Provider that had his SOAP Services awefully written, so the PHP-CLIENT class gives me a lot of validation errors. Any way, their SOAP "works", not as it should but it does.

What I wanted to do is extend from this class and modify the validation, for example for not controlling that the targetNamespace has a diffeent name that the location. I know that I shouldn't do this, but I don't want to write a SOAP Class from the scratch.

When I was trying to extend from this class ( SoapClient ) I realized that there is no code at all in the methods, and I could not find the reason why. I was thinking that maybe is because these methods works under the "C" enviroment, or that they are already compiled to make it faster. If this is not the case I would love to see the code for this class and modify it for my needs.

Any suggestions, tips or explanations are welcome. I am attaching the SoapClient Code.

```
class SoapClient  {

/**
 * (PHP 5 &gt;= 5.0.1)<br/>
 * SoapClient constructor
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php
 * @param mixed $wsdl <p>
 * URI of the WSDL file or <b>NULL</b> if working in
 * non-WSDL mode.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * During development, WSDL caching may be disabled by the
 * use of the soap.wsdl_cache_ttl <i>php.ini</i> setting
 * otherwise changes made to the WSDL file will have no effect until
 * soap.wsdl_cache_ttl is expired.
 * </p>
 * @param array $options [optional] <p>
 * An array of options. If working in WSDL mode, this parameter is optional.
 * If working in non-WSDL mode, the location and
 * uri options must be set, where location
 * is the URL of the SOAP server to send the request to, and uri
 * is the target namespace of the SOAP service.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * The style and use options only work in
 * non-WSDL mode. In WSDL mode, they come from the WSDL file.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * The soap_version option should be one of either
 * <b>SOAP_1_1</b> or <b>SOAP_1_2</b> to
 * select SOAP 1.1 or 1.2, respectively. If omitted, 1.1 is used.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * For HTTP authentication, the login and
 * password options can be used to supply credentials.
 * For making an HTTP connection through
 * a proxy server, the options proxy_host,
 * proxy_port, proxy_login
 * and proxy_password are also available.
 * For HTTPS client certificate authentication use
 * local_cert and passphrase options. An
 * authentication may be supplied in the authentication
 * option. The authentication method may be either
 * <b>SOAP_AUTHENTICATION_BASIC</b> (default) or
 * <b>SOAP_AUTHENTICATION_DIGEST</b>.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * The compression option allows to use compression
 * of HTTP SOAP requests and responses.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * The encoding option defines internal character
 * encoding. This option does not change the encoding of SOAP requests (it is
 * always utf-8), but converts strings into it.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * The trace option enables tracing of request so faults
 * can be backtraced. This defaults to <b>FALSE</b>
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * The classmap option can be used to map some WSDL
 * types to PHP classes. This option must be an array with WSDL types
 * as keys and names of PHP classes as values.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * Setting the boolean trace option enables use of the
 * methods
 * SoapClient->__getLastRequest,
 * SoapClient->__getLastRequestHeaders,
 * SoapClient->__getLastResponse and
 * SoapClient->__getLastResponseHeaders.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * The exceptions option is a boolean value defining whether
 * soap errors throw exceptions of type
 * SoapFault.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * The connection_timeout option defines a timeout in seconds
 * for the connection to the SOAP service. This option does not define a timeout
 * for services with slow responses. To limit the time to wait for calls to finish the
 * default_socket_timeout setting
 * is available.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * The typemap option is an array of type mappings.
 * Type mapping is an array with keys type_name,
 * type_ns (namespace URI), from_xml
 * (callback accepting one string parameter) and to_xml
 * (callback accepting one object parameter).
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * The cache_wsdl option is one of
 * <b>WSDL_CACHE_NONE</b>,
 * <b>WSDL_CACHE_DISK</b>,
 * <b>WSDL_CACHE_MEMORY</b> or
 * <b>WSDL_CACHE_BOTH</b>.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * The user_agent option specifies string to use in
 * User-Agent header.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * The stream_context option is a resource
 * for context.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * The features option is a bitmask of
 * <b>SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS</b>,
 * <b>SOAP_USE_XSI_ARRAY_TYPE</b>,
 * <b>SOAP_WAIT_ONE_WAY_CALLS</b>.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * The keep_alive option is a boolean value defining whether
 * to send the Connection: Keep-Alive header or
 * Connection: close.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * The ssl_method option is one of
 * <b>SOAP_SSL_METHOD_TLS</b>,
 * <b>SOAP_SSL_METHOD_SSLv2</b>,
 * <b>SOAP_SSL_METHOD_SSLv3</b> or
 * <b>SOAP_SSL_METHOD_SSLv23</b>.
 * </p>
 */
public function SoapClient ($wsdl, array $options = null) {}

/**
 * (PHP 5 &gt;= 5.0.1)<br/>
 * Calls a SOAP function (deprecated)
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.call.php
 * @param string $function_name
 * @param string $arguments
 * @return mixed
 */
public function __call ($function_name, $arguments) {}

/**
 * (PHP 5 &gt;= 5.0.1)<br/>
 * Calls a SOAP function
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php
 * @param string $function_name <p>
 * The name of the SOAP function to call.
 * </p>
 * @param array $arguments <p>
 * An array of the arguments to pass to the function. This can be either
 * an ordered or an associative array. Note that most SOAP servers require
 * parameter names to be provided, in which case this must be an
 * associative array.
 * </p>
 * @param array $options [optional] <p>
 * An associative array of options to pass to the client.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * The location option is the URL of the remote Web service.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * The uri option is the target namespace of the SOAP service.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * The soapaction option is the action to call.
 * </p>
 * @param mixed $input_headers [optional] <p>
 * An array of headers to be sent along with the SOAP request.
 * </p>
 * @param array $output_headers [optional] <p>
 * If supplied, this array will be filled with the headers from the SOAP response.
 * </p>
 * @return mixed SOAP functions may return one, or multiple values. If only one value is returned
 * by the SOAP function, the return value of __soapCall will be
 * a simple value (e.g. an integer, a string, etc). If multiple values are
 * returned, __soapCall will return
 * an associative array of named output parameters.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * On error, if the SoapClient object was constructed with the exceptions
 * option set to <b>FALSE</b>, a SoapFault object will be returned.
 */
public function __soapCall ($function_name, array $arguments, array $options = null, $input_headers = null, array &$output_headers = null) {}

/**
 * (PHP 5 &gt;= 5.0.1)<br/>
 * Returns last SOAP request
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequest.php
 * @return string The last SOAP request, as an XML string.
 */
public function __getLastRequest () {}

/**
 * (PHP 5 &gt;= 5.0.1)<br/>
 * Returns last SOAP response
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastresponse.php
 * @return string The last SOAP response, as an XML string.
 */
public function __getLastResponse () {}

/**
 * (PHP 5 &gt;= 5.0.1)<br/>
 * Returns the SOAP headers from the last request
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequestheaders.php
 * @return string The last SOAP request headers.
 */
public function __getLastRequestHeaders () {}

/**
 * (PHP 5 &gt;= 5.0.1)<br/>
 * Returns the SOAP headers from the last response
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastresponseheaders.php
 * @return string The last SOAP response headers.
 */
public function __getLastResponseHeaders () {}

/**
 * (PHP 5 &gt;= 5.0.1)<br/>
 * Returns list of available SOAP functions
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getfunctions.php
 * @return array The array of SOAP function prototypes, detailing the return type,
 * the function name and type-hinted paramaters.
 */
public function __getFunctions () {}

/**
 * (PHP 5 &gt;= 5.0.1)<br/>
 * Returns a list of SOAP types
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.gettypes.php
 * @return array The array of SOAP types, detailing all structures and types.
 */
public function __getTypes () {}

/**
 * (PHP 5 &gt;= 5.0.1)<br/>
 * Performs a SOAP request
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.dorequest.php
 * @param string $request <p>
 * The XML SOAP request.
 * </p>
 * @param string $location <p>
 * The URL to request.
 * </p>
 * @param string $action <p>
 * The SOAP action.
 * </p>
 * @param int $version <p>
 * The SOAP version.
 * </p>
 * @param int $one_way [optional] <p>
 * If one_way is set to 1, this method returns nothing.
 * Use this where a response is not expected.
 * </p>
 * @return string The XML SOAP response.
 */
public function __doRequest ($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0) {}

/**
 * (PHP 5 &gt;= 5.0.4)<br/>
 * The __setCookie purpose
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.setcookie.php
 * @param string $name <p>
 * The name of the cookie.
 * </p>
 * @param string $value [optional] <p>
 * The value of the cookie. If not specified, the cookie will be deleted.
 * </p>
 * @return void No value is returned.
 */
public function __setCookie ($name, $value = null) {}

public function __getCookies () {}

/**
 * (PHP 5 &gt;= 5.0.1)<br/>
 * Sets the location of the Web service to use
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.setlocation.php
 * @param string $new_location [optional] <p>
 * The new endpoint URL.
 * </p>
 * @return string The old endpoint URL.
 */
public function __setLocation ($new_location = null) {}

/**
 * (PHP 5 &gt;= 5.0.5)<br/>
 * Sets SOAP headers for subsequent calls
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.setsoapheaders.php
 * @param mixed $soapheaders [optional] <p>
 * The headers to be set. It could be <b>SoapHeader</b>
 * object or array of <b>SoapHeader</b> objects.
 * If not specified or set to <b>NULL</b>, the headers will be deleted.
 * </p>
 * @return bool <b>TRUE</b> on success or <b>FALSE</b> on failure.
 */
public function __setSoapHeaders ($soapheaders = null) {}
```

}

Comment: Extent the class, don't worry this is just Documentation.

Comment: I know that I can just extend it, but I need to do is change the validation process, and for this reason a need to know how it is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end the solution was not pretty at all.

In the case of connecting with the SOAP class to a service that had a lot of issues, what I did is download the WSDL structure and modify it according on what I needed.

I don't like this solution because if the API supplier change anything I don't have the knowledge to know about it.

In the following code you can see the SOAP call being called for a fixed XML and asking about the services.

```
$urlXML = "FIXEDXML.xml";
    $cliente = new SoapClient($urlXML, array(
        "trace" => true,
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
    ));

    var_dump($cliente);

    echo "<h1> FUNCIONES DISPONIBLES </h1>";
    echo '<pre>';
    $functiones = $cliente->__getFunctions();
    var_dump($functiones);
    echo '</pre>';
} catch (Exception $exc) {
    var_dump($exc);
    echo $exc->getTraceAsString();
}
```

I hope that this would be useful for someone. I was a long period of time trying to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Just do as you would do with any PHP class:

```
class mySoapClient extends SoapClient {
    //override parent function
    public function nativeFunction() {
          //...some logic ...
    }
}
```

The point is that you need to know if it will be as easy as you want. Sometimes is easier to use a third-party library, that you will have access to the code and see exaclty how to change the code.

Comment: I understand that. But I need to know the code inside to change it :)